# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)'

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to compare a month of date stored in the sql while fetching the records but it throws me the exception.

```
public partial class LateRequest
{
    public int LateRequestID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EmpID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TeamLeadAppr { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeptLeadAppr { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> lateDate { get; set; }
}
```

in my calculations Class I have;

```
public int getMonthlyLatesApproved(int empId)
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    var getMonth = today.Month
    var lateApproved = (from obj in db.LateRequests
                        where obj.EmpID == empId
                        && obj.TeamLeadAppr == 1 && obj.DeptLeadAppr == 1
                        && obj.lateDate.Value.ToString("mm") == getMonth.ToString()
                        select obj).Count();
    return lateApproved;
}
```

This did not work so I tried with LINQ like:

```
return db.LateRequests.Where(x => x.EmpID == empId && x.TeamLeadAppr == 1 && x.DeptLeadAppr == 1 &&
                                  x.lateDate.Value.ToString("mm") == getMonth.ToString()).Count();
```

This failed and I read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401166/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostringsystem-st) and tried with `AsEnumerable()`

like below;

```
 return db.LateRequests.Where(x => x.EmpID == empId && x.TeamLeadAppr == 1 && x.DeptLeadAppr == 1 &&
                                  x.lateDate.Value.ToString("mm") == getMonth.ToString()).AsEnumerable().Count();
```

`[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method.when i try to format my date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401166/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostringsystem-st)

I need to understand how am I mixing the c-sharp with sql commands while retrieving the records?

Comment: The `mm` format for a DateTime returns the minutes, not the month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the [SqlFunctions.DatePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
&& SqlFunctions.DatePart("month", obj.lateDate) == getMonth
```